# JavaFX how to change stage

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scene, scenebuilder

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 with Scene Builder 1.0 to develop a JavaFX application. I have my main screen set up, and I want to have it so I click a button and it'll close the main window and open another. The main Stage object is located in the main class, but the controller class is separate, and can't access it since it's not static and in a different class. How do I change the scene or stage?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Download JavaFX samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html) find the project FXML-LoginDemo , that's what you need. For quick reference i am copy pasting main java class here ;)

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 2011 Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 * This file is available and licensed under the following license:
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *  - Neither the name of Oracle Corporation nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
package demo;

import demo.model.User;
import demo.security.Authenticator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Main Application. This class handles navigation and user session.
 */
public class App extends Application {
    private Stage stage;
    private User loggedUser;

    private static App instance;

    public App() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            stage = primaryStage;
            gotoLogin();
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public User getLoggedUser() {
        return loggedUser;
    }

    public boolean userLogging(String userId, String password){
        if (Authenticator.validate(userId, password)) {
            loggedUser = User.of(userId);
            gotoProfile();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void userLogout(){
        loggedUser = null;
        gotoLogin();
    }

    private void gotoProfile() {
        try {
            replaceSceneContent("profile.fxml");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void gotoLogin() {
        try {
            replaceSceneContent("login.fxml");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private Parent replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
        Parent page = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(App.class.getResource(fxml), null, new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        Scene scene = stage.getScene();
        if (scene == null) {
            scene = new Scene(page, 700, 450);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(App.class.getResource("demo.css").toExternalForm());
            stage.setScene(scene);
        } else {
            stage.getScene().setRoot(page);
        }
        stage.sizeToScene();
        return page;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this correctly nowdays? i mean, can i use this and call outside the App class the .replaceSceneContent? or today(year 2015) is there a correct way of doing the change between stages? thanks =)

Comment: how can I use this in a Controller class? Or can I use this only in the main app?

Comment: This answer is old and today it is out of date :(

Answer (score 6):

I'm probably saying something similar here, but this is how I do it:

(In this example, I am transitioning from Login.fxml to Home.fxml).

Inside the LoginController.fxml class, I have created the following method:

```
@FXML
private void login(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    if(pwf1.getText().equals("dolphin"))
    {
            Parent blah = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(blah);
            Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            appStage.setScene(scene);
            appStage.show();
    }
    else
    {
            label1.setText("Password is incorrect. Please Try Again");
    }
}
```

And that's it.;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way too:

Modify your controller.java this way

```
Stage thisStage;

public void setStage (Stage stage){
    thisStage = stage;
}

public void showStage(){
    thisStage.setTitle("Titel in der MainController.java geändert");
    thisStage.show();
}
```

It is important that you don't use thisStage in the initialize method.

Modify your Mainclass this way:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    URL location = getClass().getResource("Main.fxml");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
    fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    MainController mainController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    mainController.setStage(stage);
    mainController.showStage();
}
```

You can download a example projekt (netbeans) [here](http://jacktoolsnet.de/myfaq/images/JavaFX/projekte/controllerwithstage.zip).

Comment: link is broken, can you give as another one?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, recently I was working on developing an iOS equivalent NavigationController for JavaFX, using the simplest idea of push and dismiss views.

Let me share the code with the community: https://github.com/jalopezsuarez/javafx-screens

The idea, is to have a very very easy environment to help you change between screens.

Hope it helps you.