# Passing parameters to javafx controller method not working

Tags: java, javafx, controllers

I have a **Pane** component stored in a **fxml** file. I'm importing this component to another Scene, and I want this component to show with auto-generated information. So I searched this exact question and I found this: [Passing parameters to a controller when loading an FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370183/passing-parameters-to-a-controller-when-loading-an-fxml). This what they do:

```
 private void addReservation(Reservation r) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmloader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/item_reserva.fxml"));
            Pane client = (Pane) fxmloader.load();
            Item_reservaController controller = fxmloader.<Item_reservaController>getController();
            controller.init(r);
            flowPane.getChildren().add(client);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm loading the component to the *Parent* type in this case **Pane**. And then I'm calling its controller and initializing the components and finally showing the **Pane** inside a **Flowpane**.

This is what the init method does:

```
public void init(Reservation r) {
    this.reservation = r;
    labelCountry = new Label(r.getClients().getFirst().getCountry());
    labelRoom = new Label(Integer.toString(r.getRooms().size()));
    labelClient = new Label(Integer.toString(r.getClients().size()));
}
```

I guess that the problem is related with that the object I'm drawing is not the same as the controller I'm changing, so it wont change the information inside the real components.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your problem _is_. Do you get an exception? Does the pane not show? Does it show without the `Reservation` info?  

Do you use the labels created in the `init` method?

Comment: It shows without the reservation info. And no the labels are already defined in the fxml file.

Comment: Where do you add the labels to the pane? Please include that part of the code as well.

Comment: The labels are defined in the fxml file. I used Scene Builder to create the FXML file, and I manually added the labels and use the ids shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `init` method is called after loading the fxml, it's unlikely that the `Label`s created in that method are added to the scene.

> And no the labels are already defined in the fxml file.

Since the scene already contains the appropriate `Label`s, use those `Label`s instead of creating new ones. If the `Label`s are sucessfully injected to the controller, just use `setText` to assign the content:

```
public void init(Reservation r) {
    this.reservation = r;
    labelCountry.setText(r.getClients().getFirst().getCountry());
    labelRoom.setText(Integer.toString(r.getRooms().size()));
    labelClient.setText(Integer.toString(r.getClients().size()));
}
```

Comment: Have you overwritten the field value somewhere else? Were they sucessfully injected to the controller?

Comment: No I haven't, does this method works for you? Is there any other way to initialize a controller?